# Enterprise Library 4.1 Exception policy

Tags: exception, enterprise-library, policy

I am using Enterprise Library 4.1 and want to implement Exception handling and logging.
I am able to setup one policy that handles general Exceptions of the System.Exception type. I call this policy 'Data Access Policy'.

In a general application development rule, how many policies should I create?
What are the best practices for catching SqlExceptions? Should a separate policy be defined?

What I am looking for is some suggestions from folks who develop applications using Enterprise Library and how they setup the policies for exception handling and some examples would help.

Thanks

Comment: is there really something called "enterprise library"???

Comment: Yes there is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new policy for SqlExceptions.

Here is a great post for you: [Enterprise Library 4.1 :: Exception Handling Application Block](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/04/microsoft-enterprise-library-4-1-exception-handling-block.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late for you now but this link may help someone else. It's a page from the Enterprise Library documentation entitled ["Determining Appropriate Exception Policies and Actions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647137.aspx) and does exactly what it says on the tin